# Topological sort complexity in linear time?

Tags: python-3.x, time-complexity, complexity-theory, topological-sort

I am trying to calculate the algorithmic complexity of Kahn's algorithm implemented in python, I came across this article :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting-indegree-based-solution/
in the part of the code for calculating the degree of all nodes has this

```
for each node in Nodes
    If (list[node].size()!=0) then
        for each dest in list
            indegree[dest]++;
```

in the article it says that the complexity is O(V+E), but why? there are two nested fors, shouldn't it be O(V*E) ?

I wrote an implementation in python something like this:

```py
for vertex in graph:                    # O(V) * O(E) = O(V * E). ??
    for edge in graph[vertex]:          # O(E)+O(1) => O(E)
        indegree[dege] += 1             # O(1)
```

V = # of vertex of the graph

E = # of edges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is notation often used in graph algorithms to specify how dependent the algorithm is on the density of the graph. `E` is always `O(V^2)`, but that bound may not be tight. Say there aren't many edges (for example, a tree, where there are exactly `V - 1` edges). Then `O(V + E) = O(V + V) = O(2V) = O(V)`.

Now consider a dense graph (for example, a complete graph, where there are at least `V(V-1)` edges, or more if self edges are allowed). Now `O(V+E) = O(V + V^2 - V) = O(V^2)`.

Inside `O(...)`, `+` behaves somewhat like `max`: the overall complexity is determined by the larger of the two addends. This basically gives you a kind of shorthand for showing how the complexity grows along two axes: one, the number of vertices, and two, the density of the edges.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, the complexity would be more accurately stated as `V + 2E` (which has overall complexity class `O(V + E)`. We iterate over each vertex exactly once, and each edge exactly twice (once for each vertex it's attached to) - assuming that `graph[vertex]` returns only the edges attached to that vertex, which seems to be the algorithm's intention.

Nested loops *does* usually indicate a `*` instead of a `+`, where complexity is concerned. If the inner loop is iterating over something different than the outer loop, however, we sometimes get cases like this - where there's a specific and constant number of things across *all* inner loops, distributed somehow across each element of the outer loops.

In such a case, we can indeed write the complexity as `O(V + E)`, because the number of `E` we iterate over isn't tied in any way to the number of `V` we iterate over - just the order in which we do so, which complexity doesn't really care about.